# ForeignKey relationship on 0 or >0 value (EF 6.1)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm currently learning Entity Framework (6.1) by creating a model by code on an existing database, so unfortunately **I can't change the database structure** so I'm have loads of headaches with it, but slowly working my way through the problems and searching for them online, but I've hit one that I can't find an answer to.

I have two classes- broken down for easy display here, they have more fields but not needed here.

```
partial class detail {
  public int id {get; set;}
  public int owner {get; set;}
  public string data {get;set;}

  [ForeignKey("owner")]
  public virtual owner theowner {get;set;}
}

partial class owner {
  public int ownercode {get;set;}
  public string name {get;set;}

  [ForeignKey("ownercode")]
  public virtual ICollection<detail> ownerdetails {get;set;}
}
```

*(detail can only have one owner, but an owner can have many details)*

The problem I'm having is the "owner" field in the detail table can ether be **0** or a number **>0**. if it's zero then there is **no owner**, if it's >0 then there should be an owner (theowner virtual property).

I've tried putting the following in the OnModelCreating,

```
modelBuilder.Entity<detail>()
  .HasOptional(o => o.owner);
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> mynamespace.detail_owner: : Multiplicity conflicts with the
>   referential constraint in Role 'detail_owner_Target' in relationship
>   'detail_owner'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role
>   are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.

So the question I have is how do I map the "theowner" virtual property in the detail class to the owner class when the "owner" property is greater than zero, and when it's zero "theowner" property should be null.

Comment: Try on the DataModel, in the ForeignKey Association, set the End1 Multiplicity to 0..1(Zero or One..)

Comment: Or set public Nullable<int> owner {get; set;}

Comment: @SílvioN. As this is an old DB the owner value has to be a number, can't be null and I can't change it. I don't have a DataModel, I created the classes using "codefirst from database".